# Expand div automatically when floated sibling is hidden

Tags: html, css

Is it possibly to automatically expand a div to maximum width once it's floated sibling style set to `display:none`?

Please take a look at this example:
[image]

Comment: There are several ways to do it. I would use flexbox (`display: flex` on the parent element of these two),

Comment: consider using `flex` elements - http://jsbin.com/piyidenoje/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy with flexbox - children expand by default:

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.querySelector(".b").classList.toggle("hidden");
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex; /* this is the important bit */
}

div {
  border: 0.1em solid black;
  margin: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.b {
  width: 15%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean eu felis at metus convallis ornare. Pellentesque in porttitor elit. Sed augue augue, vulputate in laoreet quis, vehicula et arcu. Nullam feugiat elit purus, id euismod ligula sodales nec. Vestibulum mattis molestie lacus. <button>Toggle B</button>
</div>
<div class="b"></div>
```

Browser support is really good for some time now: https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Another option would be `display: table`:

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.querySelector(".b").classList.toggle("hidden");
});
```

```css
body {
  display: table;
  border-spacing: 1em;
  border-collapse: separate;
}

.a, .b {
  border: 0.1em solid black;
  padding: 0.5em;
  display: table-cell;
  height: 5em;
}

.a {
  width: 85%;
}

.b {
  width: 15%;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean eu felis at metus convallis ornare. Pellentesque in porttitor elit. Sed augue augue, vulputate in laoreet quis, vehicula et arcu. Nullam feugiat elit purus, id euismod ligula sodales nec.
  Vestibulum mattis molestie lacus. <button>Toggle B</button>
</div>
<div class="b"></div>
```

But… it feels kinda hacky to me. Just use flexbox if you don't need support for ancient browsers.

Comment: Thank you, the behavior is exactly what I was looking for. I wish it was also supported for IE9.

Comment: @Oleg: there's also `display: table` and `table-cell`. But i haven't got IE9 around to test it. Example here: https://codepen.io/helb/pen/qVRGKN

Answer (score 1):

This is how I'd do it. See if it works for you.

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.querySelector(".a").classList.toggle("hidden");
});
```

```css
body{
  display: block;
}
.container{
  width: 96%;
  margin-left: 2%;
}
.a, .b {
  float: right;
  height: 5em;
}
.a {
  width: 15%;
  background: #00E676;
}
.b {
  width: 85%;
  background: #1E88E5;
  font-family: Calibri;
  line-height: 2em;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.hidden ~ .b{
  width: 100%;
}
button{
  margin: 100px 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
</div>
<button>Toggle</button>
```